# How to achieve groupby in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not very familiar with LinQ and i have a small(i think) problem. Basically i' deserializing an xml file to the array of following items:

```
public string stringId{ get; set; }
public string sgent { get; set; }
public string status{ get; set; }
public string recallDate { get; set; }
public string product{ get; set; }
public string sendMethod{ get; set; }
public string campaign{ get; set; }
public string comment{ get; set; }
public string sgentId{ get; set; }
public string dateOfSell { get; set; }
```

My list so far looks like this

```
var model = from r in selling.sales
            where r.sgentId == idFromLoginAction.ToString()
            orderby r.dateOfSell
            select r;
```

It works but What I want to achieve is to get list of this items groupped by dateOfSell property so later on i can show this in the view in the way where Date property will be shown only once for every same date and below this date i want to show the list of all other properties where dateOfSell property was this speciffic date.

I'm pretty sure i Can achieve this groupping with LinQ. Am I right ? Is it possible, or it's a bad approach ?
Bellow i've wrote a little sketch to show what is my point:

```
2014-01-08
Prop 1    Prop2    Prop3    prop4 ... etc
Prop 1    Prop2    Prop3    Prop4 ... etc
2014-01-07
Prop 1    Prop2    Prop3    prop4 ... etc
Prop 1    Prop2    Prop3    Prop4 ... etc
ETC ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GroupBy` this way, do like this before `Select` :

```
var model = from r in selling.sales 
            where r.sgentId == idFromLoginAction.ToString() 
            orderby r.dateOfSell
            group r by r.dateOfSell into g
            select new { DateOfSell = g.Key, Sales = g.ToList() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = selling.sales.GroupBy(s => s.dateOfSell, (key, g) => new { SellDate = key, OtherValues = g.ToList() });
```

Then you can do:

```
        foreach(var item in result){
// Your key you grouped By
    var selDate = item.SellDate;

// List of Other Items
    var groupedItems = item.OtherValues;


        }
```

Look at the link mentioned by @Devqon: [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)